# How to exclude URLs from IIS URL Rewrites when it contains an specific string

Tags: iis, url-rewriting, url-rewrite-module

I have the following URL:

```
http://localhost:4423/DXR.axd?r=1_84-0iUmm
```

And the following IIS Rewrite Rule:

```
<rule name="Enforce LowerCase" enabled="true" stopProcessing="true">
  <match url="(.*)" />
  <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll" >
    <add input="{URL}" pattern="[A-Z]" ignoreCase="false" /> 
  </conditions>
  <action type="Redirect" url="{ToLower:{URL}}" redirectType="Permanent" />
</rule>
```

I would the rule do not apply if it conains DXR.axd. Can you please share your thoughts. Thanks.

Comment: According to your description, I couldn’t understand your requirement clearly. which url do you want to redirect to?

Comment: I want to exclude any URL that has DXR.axd in it. Any other url can be enforced to have the lower case applied.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HTTP queries consist of a protocol, domain, path and query string, your url is constructed of 4 discrete elements:

- Protocol: http://
- Domain: localhost:4423
- Path: /DXR.axd
- Query string: r=1_84-0iUmm

If you want to match any string without `/DXR.axd`, you only need to set your parameters like this：

```
<match url="^(?!/DXR.axd$).*$" />
```